# The authblk package seems to prevent customizing \maketitle width

Tags: titles, width, tikzposter, authblk

I am attempting to make a title block on a poster that has authors with references to their affiliations (using authblk) as well as customizing the width of the title block.  Changing the width works fine without the authblk package:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{tikzposter}
\title{Title}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle[width=0.75\textwidth]
\end{document}
```

However, as soon as I add the package:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{tikzposter}
\usepackage{authblk}
\title{Title}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle[width=0.75\textwidth]
\end{document}
```

I get this error: Missing number, treated as zero. \maketitle[width=0.75\textwidth]

I don't see why I shouldn't be able to do both of these things at the same time, so this seems like a bug to me.  Is there some width associated with authblk that I should be using instead of \textwidth?  Or just some other way of making this work?

Comment: Maketitle does not normally take any arguments or options, so other packages never consider this. This is bønot really a bug, but rather a case of two systems (authblk and tikzposter) that are incompatible.

Comment: Ok, I see what you're saying.  Any suggestions on how to get around it?

Comment: Rephrasing your question with a more suitable title and tagged with tikzposter might help getting more to help.